# Taking Backup of files of particular limit in unix

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, tar

Here is the scenario, I have 1000 files in a folder each ~3 MB. I want to zip all files into 50MB each zip and remove the original files.

**NOTE:** 50MB may contain 20 files or 10 files but that zip package should be <=50MB.

I want to transfer those files without data loss. File must be of format (tar/gzip/bzip). Please provide suggestions to me if we have any other way to overcome the data loss.

Need to create a shell script.

Comment: Curious as to what the 50MB limit is for.

Comment: If you don't want to use split and you're happy with some fuzzy logic you could create a bash script that looped through the list of files and zipped a fixed number each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the split command.

The split command will split an archive in to multiple files, doing all the hard work for you.

Here is an example:

```
tar -cvf - file1 file2 file3 | split --bytes=50m --suffix-length=4 --numeric-suffix - myarchive.tar.
```

And to untar:

```
cat myarchive.tar.* | tar xvf -
```

Comment: Thanks, It works. if I have 50 MB files in tar format..it would be better in transferring files through network without dataloss

Comment: That's great. When you're ready don't forget to select the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `zip` package supports **bzip2** compression and `--split`.

Will bzip2 meet your requirements?

> -s splitsize
>   --split-size splitsize
>       Enable creating a split archive and set the split size. A split archive is an archive that could be split over many files. As the
>   archive is created, if the size of the archive reaches the specified
>   split size, that split is closed and the next split opened.
>
> ...
>
> Split size is a number optionally followed by a multiplier. Currently the number must be an integer. The multiplier can currently
>   be one of k (kilobytes), m (megabytes), g (gigabytes), or t
>   (terabytes). As 64k is the minimum split size, numbers without
>   multipliers default to megabytes. For example, to create a split
>   archive called foo with the contents of the bar directory with splits
>   of 670 MB that might be useful for burning on CDs, the command:
>
> zip -s 670m -r foo bar
>
> could be used.

To ensure data integrity, `rsync` with checksum verification. It's much slower, but will calculate checksum on both sides of the transfer.

> -c, --checksum
>
> This changes the way rsync checks if the files have been changed and are in need of a transfer. Without this option, rsync uses a
>   lqquick checkrq that (by default) checks if each file's size and time
>   of last modification match between the sender and receiver. This
>   option changes this to compare a 128-bit checksum for each file that
>   has a matching size. Generating the checksums means that both sides
>   will expend a lot of disk I/O reading all the data in the files in the
>   transfer (and this is prior to any reading that will be done to
>   transfer changed files), so this can slow things down significantly.

From: [`man zip`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip), [`man rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Answer (score 0):

untested

```
cd /the/directory
files=(*)
i=0
z=0
create_zip=true
for ((i=0; i<${#files[@]}; i++)); do
    if $create_zip; then
        ((z++))
        zip_file=prefix.$z.zip
        create_zip=false
    fi
    # add the file
    zip $zip_file "${files[i]}"
    # check the size
    if (( $(stat -c %s $zip_file) >= 50000000 )); then
        # remove the previous file
        zip -d $zip_file "${files[i]}"
        create_zip=true
        # decrement the file index so this file gets added to the next zip
        ((i--))
    else
        echo rm "${files[i]}"            ### remove "echo" if it's OK
    fi
done
```

Comment: So basically keep creating zip archives until one is larger than 50MB, then use the last one? Sounds like a great way to waste CPU cycles and disk IO.